# 小数点の表示形式について

Tags: ruby

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
以下のような計算した場合

```
num1 =  0.00000387
num2 = num1 * 1.03
p num2.floor(10) => #3.9861e-06
```

とe指数部というような形で返ってきますが、これをe指数部という形で略すのではなく0.0000039861といった形で表示したいのですが上手くいきません。
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すみません、質問内容が全く足りていませんでした。num1は変数でnum1=0.00000387であったり、num1=0.000298であったり、その都度違い、さらに小数点以下の最後の0の部分は表示しないようにしたいのです。計算結果が0.0003069400であれば0.00030694と表示すると言った感じです。また、最終的にはそれを文字列として使用したいのですがなかなか上手くいかない状態です。説明が分かりづらくて申し訳ありませんが、アドバイス頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: noity さん、スタックオーバーフローでは質問文下の「編集」から質問文に直接追記できますので、是非ご利用くださいませ。後からこのご質問を見に来た方からはその方が読みやすいです。

Comment: ruby の Float クラスのインスタンスの場合、小数点以下15桁が精度の上限らしいので、`('%.15f' % num2.floor(10)).sub(/0+$/, '')` といったところでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！上手く出来ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sprintf`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/print_format.html)を使うのはいかがでしょうか？

```
num1 = 0.00000387
num2 = num1 * 1.03
p sprintf("%.10f", num2) # => "0.0000039861"
```